# What's the name of this plant?

Tags: identification, flowers

I just bought a new plant but I forgot to ask what's the name.  Can you recognize it?  Any suggestion about how to take care of it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is a cultivar of [Cyclamen persicum, the Persian cyclamen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclamen_persicum). This plant is native to the Mediterranean area and is not hardy in areas colder than around zero degrees Fahrenheit. It has a large tuber which it uses to store energy and water over the long hot summer.  If the plant enters dormancy all the leaves die and it should be kept drier until it grows new leaves.

From the [cyclamen society](http://www.cyclamen.org/faq_set.html) they recommend:

> Cyclamen pot plants need a light position, but not too much direct
>   sunlight. A window sill which does not face south is ideal, but on
>   frosty nights, unless you have double glazing, you should bring it
>   into the room. It will be happy at normal room temperatures, but
>   shouldn't get too hot, and will last much longer in a cool position
>   (55°F/13°C). Watering incorrectly can cause the most problems,
>   generally when too much water has been given. Always wait until the
>   compost feels fairly dry, but avoid waiting so long that the plant
>   becomes limp. You can water from either the top or the bottom, but
>   afterwards the pot should be allowed to drain properly, and any water
>   remaining in the saucer or pot-holder after 5 minutes, should be
>   tipped away. If possible, avoid splashing the centre of the plant with
>   water. You can feed with a pot-plant liquid food... about
>   every 2 weeks, but be aware that overfeeding is more likely to produce
>   foliage rather than flowers. Dead flowers or leaves should be removed
>   carefully by giving their stems a sharp tug

The requirement for cool temperatures ( ~50 degrees Fahrenheit at night) seems to be the key to success with these plants.  In sunny climates a north facing window is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a cyclamen to me. Here are [more pictures](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cyclamens) so you can compare. The general consensus is that they don't need a lot of fuss and bother. That matches with my memory of having them in my house when I was young - my mother was very hard on houseplants but we usually had one of these around.